# Angular CSS Row Hover Text Change

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

New to Angular.  I'm trying to make an entire row change font color on hover.  I have the background color working fine, but I can only seem to get one cell to change color at a time, rather than all cells in the row. I'm using Material library and ng-container.

```
<div>
  <table class="order-summary" mat-table [dataSource]="orderSummary" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let order"><fa-icon [icon]="getTypeIcon(order.type)"></fa-icon></td>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns"></mat-row>
  </table>
</div>

.mat-row:hover{
  background-color: rgba(119, 119, 122, 0.1);
}

.mat-row:hover{
  color:  #FB792A;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your styles to this:

```
.mat-row:hover{
  background-color: rgba(119, 119, 122, 0.1);
}

.mat-row:hover > .mat-cell {
  color:  #FB792A;
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3atzrf?file=app/table-basic-example.css) for your ref.